# How can I detect the version of DbgHelp at compile time?

Tags: visual-c++, dbghelp

The [reference manual for DbgHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) nicely lists all the versions and what changes they introduced. How can I detect the version at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

The [ImagehlpApiVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function retrieves the version information of the DbgHelp library installed on the system.

To indicate the version of the library with which the application was built, use the [ImagehlpApiVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: You can use these API in your build process.

Comment: I'd rather not have to do that. Also, technically that's still not "compile-time".

Comment: You could detect the version of DbgHelp using these API during your Pre-Built step. You cannot (of course) ask your compiler to accomplish that task for you (the job of a compiler is to compile, not more not less).